# Does a compiled Rust executable exclude unused code from dependencies?

Tags: rust, dependencies, rust-cargo

If I build a Rust application using Cargo with some crate dependencies, will any code in those dependencies that is unused by my application be eliminated from the final executable?

Comment: I think yes, but I'm not sure.

Comment: I could probably check with objdump or something similar but I want to see if there's a definitive answer or if it's planned for a future release. There's a related issue with the size of hello-world type executables.

Comment: With LTO for sure, otherwise I'm not that certain.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It looks like it. I made a test lib and bin crate side by side:

```
// hellobin/src/main.rs

extern crate hellolib;

fn main() {
    hellolib::func1();
}
```

For the lib:

```
// hellolib/src/main.rs

pub fn func1() {
    println!("Hello, world!");
}

pub fn func2() {
    println!("Hello, other world!");
}
```

Building my binary and then inspecting symbols with `nm`:

```
$ nm target/debug/helloworld | grep hello
0000000100001360 t __ZN10helloworld4main17h749f61fb726f0a10E
00000001000014b0 T __ZN8hellolib5func117hec0b5301559d46f6E
```

Only the used function has a symbol in the final binary.

You can compile with `cargo rustc -- -C link-dead-code` though and you will see both symbols are present, including the unused one:

```
$ nm target/debug/helloworld | grep hello
0000000100001270 t __ZN10helloworld4main17h3104b73b00fdd798E
00000001000013d0 T __ZN8hellolib5func117hec0b5301559d46f6E
0000000100001420 T __ZN8hellolib5func217hc9d0886874057b84E
```

I believe (but I'm not sure) that it's the linker removing the dead code, so it may have still been compiled and then removed during linking.

Comment: Nice :) I'll accept that as the answer unless someone comes up with something definitive from the rust docs/project.

Answer (score 9):

TL;DR: Yes, every unused function is going to be excluded.

This is actually the job of LLVM that will at least keep track of every unused function. *Any unused code* (as in codepaths in function not taken across the entire Application) may require LTO (Link Time Optimizations) to be activated to turn your crate into one compilation unit and give LLVM a fighting chance.

Comment: I edited the answer to clarify that the `tl;dr yes` refers to unused functions in particular.